# Reading from file double value using Scanner - InputMismatchException?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

I tried read from file double values and using `Scanner` with this aim.

It throws [`InputMismatchException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html) :

```
"input.txt"  java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2456)
```

And I can't understand why this happen?

**Code:**

```
public class Largest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        String filename = "input.txt"; 
        Scanner in = new Scanner(filename);

        double largest = in.nextDouble();
        while (in.hasNextDouble())
        {
            double input = in.nextDouble();
            if (input > largest)
            {
                largest = input;
            }
        }
        in.close();
        System.out.println("Largest value: " + largest);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I tried change `double largest = in.nextDouble();` to `double largest = 0;`
But it get wrong input:

```
filename     Actual              Expected
-------------------------------------------------------------
"input.txt"  Largest value: 0.0  Largest value: 1.343239923E9
"input2.txt" Largest value: 0.0  Largest value: 40.1
```

**File content is like this:**

```
89343455
46746846
56.78
55486411
```

How to solve this trouble?

Comment: double largest = in.nextDouble(); line causing issue. Input you are getting at this line seems not a double value.

Comment: @Nambari How to circumvent this issue? Itried make `double largest = 0`. Is't arises exception but input is wrong - largest = 0.0

Comment: Do same check, hasNextDouble(), then only get double.

Comment: @Ravi Thapliyal It's wrong we can't check largest if this double won't larger then 0. Larger keep being larger all time...

Comment: post your
 input here.

Comment: @nazar_art where is the sample input? copy paste the content of input.txt

Comment: @nazar_art Check with my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution - need to create File object and then feed it to scanner class:

```
String filename = "input.txt"; 
File newFile = new File(filename);
Scanner in = new Scanner(newFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

- Initialise *largest* to the *first* double (after checking the type)
- Use the correct *delimiter* to parse your input (`\n` = newline)

  ```
  String filename = "input.txt"; 
  Scanner in = new Scanner(filename).useDelimiter("\\n");

  double largest;
  if (in.hasNextDouble())
      largest = in.nextDouble();

  while (in.hasNextDouble())
  {
      double input = in.nextDouble();
      if (input > largest)
      {
          largest = input;
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: It doesn't work `Actual is - Largest value: 4.9E-324` and `Expected is - Largest value: 1.343239923E9` Doesn't work

Comment: Can you also post your file contents?

Comment: @nazar_art Check my updated answer. You need to parse your file line by line since every input is on a new one.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  `new Scanner("input.txt")` creates a scanner for reading a string, not a file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileNotFoundException; 
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass{
public static void main(String[] args)
        throws FileNotFoundException
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("D:\\input.txt"));
    String largestNum=in.next().trim();
    double largest = Double.parseDouble(largestNum);
    while (in.hasNextDouble())
    {
        String Num=in.next().trim();
        double input = Double.parseDouble(Num);
        if (input > largest)
        {
            largest = input;
        }
    }
    in.close();
    System.out.println("Largest value: " + largest);
} }
```

Comment: It's not correct to assume each double is on a separate line; specially, when the OP's code clearly never used a *nextLine()*.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal in that case you can use next();