# How to read a double from a file using Scanner without InputMismatchException

Tags: java, double, java.util.scanner, primitive, inputmismatchexception

I am doing a simple task. I am assigning strings, ints, and a double to variables. The variables are being assigned through a scanner reading a text file. The scanner cannot read the double. It throws a input mismatch exception. I have researched stack overflow for the answer and I have tried the following solutions:

- [Scanner double value - InputMismatchException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150627/scanner-double-value-inputmismatchexception)
- [Scanner InputMismatchException from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40522243/scanner-inputmismatchexception-from-file)
- [How to read double in java from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35477731/how-to-read-double-in-java-from-a-file)
- [Reading from file double value using Scanner - InputMismatchException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407370/reading-from-file-double-value-using-scanner-inputmismatchexception)

The text file reads as follows:

> Pebbles Flinstone\n
>
> 1 2.2\n
>
> This is a line of text\n

This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
       File file = new File("input.txt");
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
       String s1 = scanner.next(); // s1 is assigned to Pebbles
       String s2 = scanner.next(); // s2 is assigned to Flintstone
       int x = scanner.nextInt(); // x is assigned to 1
       double y = scanner.nextDouble(); // y is assigned to 2.2
       scanner.nextLine(); // Advance scanner to beginning of next line
       String s3 = scanner.nextLine();
       scanner.close(); // s3 is assigned to "This is a line of text"
       System.out.print(y);
   }
```

How do I get the scanner to read 2.2 as a double? Changing the Locale doesn't work. Changing the decimal to a comma does not work either.

Comment: `scanner.nextDouble()`, what else? Check your input and try putting lines of `System.out.println();` to see if you inputted it wrong.

Comment: When I run this when reading from the console it works fine. I'm guessing you have a part of the file that isn't properly formatted

Comment: remove the \n from your input file and it'll work fine. to indicate a new line just hit return (enter) in your file. dont use \n